# Постепенная отрисовка графика JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, диаграммы, график

Хочу сделать плавную отрисовку графика в JavaFX, сейчас график рисуется как-то странно, как-будто "натягивается" на координаты, а необходимо, чтобы линия графика рисовалась постепенно от одной координате к другой, что можете посоветовать?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ForCyber extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
    }

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();


        HBox root = new HBox();
        lineChart.getData().add(series1);
        root.getChildren().add(lineChart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 650, 330);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);



        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(i, i*10));
        }

        for (XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series : lineChart.getData()) {
            for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data : series.getData()) {
                StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) data.getNode();
                stackPane.setVisible(false);
            }
        }


        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен термин "натягивается", но как вариант: отключить анимацию, принудительно задать границы осей( заместо автоподбора )